# Java ResultSet: Does the DB only update if updateRow is called?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, resultset

In java.sql.ResulSet, can the updateObject, updateString, update[Type] methods update the underlying database without a call to updateRow()?

Thanks,
ktm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a `ResultSet` object is created with update capability, you can call `updateXXX()` methods to update column values to prepare for calling `updateRow()` or `insertRow()` method store the updated row or a new row to the target table.

So `updateXXX()` methods do not update without call to `updateRow()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, I think the question is whenther you can update without a call to the updateRow or insertRow. At first I also missed the "without" part.

Comment: @CoolBeans, @ktm5124: if this is the case then you can use PreparedStatement to update the db.

Comment: Surely. I am not sure of the OP's intentions. I was just trying to clarify the question.

Comment: @CoolBeans: i'm also just providing option if thats the case.

Comment: @CoolBeans: Harry Joy interpeted my question correctly. I wanted to know if updateXXX ever updated without a call to updateRow. Thanks.